# How to fix InternalError: too much recursion?

Tags: loops, canvas

There is a canvas effect that needs to be looped, but it gives an error after 3-4 minutes of work, and then everything freezes. How to fix it?

```
    _this.loop = function (callback) {
        callback();
        reqAnimFrame(function () {
            _this.loop(function () {
                callback();
            });});};
var reqAnimFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || function (callback) {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);};
```